# Replacing Evernote with Emacs and markdown - .org file list

Tags: scripting, emacs

I have grown tired of using evernote with wine or with any of the linux clients. I decided to change to Emacs and write all my notes in markdown so I can easily publish them in HTML and sync them with Dropbox. For organizing my notes I thought of putting them in separate folders and having a script make a .org file with a list of all my .md files.
The structure I imagined was something like this:

```
* ~/Dropbox/Notebook1/

** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook1/notefile1.md][notefile1]]
** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook1/notefile2.md][notefile2]]


* ~/Dropbox/Notebook2/

** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook2/notefile3.md][notefile3]]
** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook2/notefile4.md][notefile4]]


* ~/Dropbox/Notebook3/

** ~/Dropbox/Notebook3.1/
*** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook3.1/Notefile5.md][notefile5]]
*** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook3.1/Notefile6.md][notefile6]]

** ~/Dropbox/Notebook3.2/
*** [[~/Dropbox/Notebook3.2/Notefile7.md][notefile7]]
```

The problem is that my scripting/programming skills are somewhere between very basic to none.
I figured that I should begin with something like "find ~/Dropbox/ -name '*md' > list", but then I got lost.
How can I take the output and manipulate it into the structure above?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to loop over the results like this:

```
for file in `find ~/Dropbox -name '*.md'`; do; echo "[[$file]]"; done
```

But, I think a solution that will help you out in the long run, would be to use the built-in indexing features of Emacs Org Mode.  You can specify your sources files in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: You could also use `shopt -s globstar` and then: `for file in ~/Dropbox/**/*.md; do ...` -- this will probably be marginally faster than the find version (since it's not calling an extra external command, although this won't be noticeable in your case), and will be more protected against funny filenames.